# Could not a create folder on mega.py API

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrT07.png)
This the error i'm getting when executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py/issues/15
I got a temporary work around on their github page.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

The problem is in the `find_path_descriptor` function (line: 289) in the `mega.py` package.

### Debugging

1. I commented lines 305:309

```py
# if (file[1]['a'] and file[1]['t']
#         and file[1]['a']['n'] == foldername):
#     if parent_desc == file[1]['p']:
#         parent_desc = file[0]
#         found = True
```

2. Above that (line: 305) I inserted the line below to return `file[1]['a']` with its type

```py
print(type(file[1]['a']), file[1]['a'])
```

3. I called the `find_path_descriptor` function

```py
m.find_path_descriptor("test")
```

here is the output:
(I replaced the values with 'name-i', 'string-i' and 'value-i' to hide my mega files' information)

```py
<class 'dict'> {'n': 'name-1'}
<class 'dict'> {'n': 'name-2'}
<class 'dict'> {'n': 'name-3'}
<class 'dict'> {'c': 'value-4', 'n': 'name-4'}
<class 'dict'> {'c': 'value-5', 'n': 'name-5'}
<class 'dict'> {'c': 'value-6', 'n': 'name-6'}
...
<class 'dict'> {'c': 'value-23', 'n': 'name-23'}
<class 'dict'> {'c': 'value-24', 'n': 'name-24'}
<class 'str'> 'string-25'
<class 'str'> 'string-26'
<class 'str'> 'string-27'
```

As you see, sometimes `file[1]['a']` is a `<class 'dict'>` but sometimes it's a `<class 'str'>`.
The `<class 'str'>` ones cause the `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

You get the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error when you try to access a character using its string value rather the index number.

That's exactly what's happening when `find_path_descriptor` tries to access the `'n'` key like this: `file[1]['a']['n']` (because it expects `file[1]['a']` to be a `<class 'dict'>`).
That's why you get the error.

### Fix

1. Don't forget to undo step 1 and step 2 before you apply the fix

   - Remove the print line (line: 305)
   - Uncomment the lines 305:309
2. Insert the line below at the top of the for statement's body (at line: 305) to verify if `file[1]['a']` is a `<class 'dict'>` or else just skip it with `continue`.

```py
if (not (type(file[1]['a']) is dict)):
    continue
```

Now your `find_path_descriptor` function should look like this:

```py
    def find_path_descriptor(self, path, files=()):
        """
        Find descriptor of folder inside a path. i.e.: folder1/folder2/folder3
        Params:
            path, string like folder1/folder2/folder3
        Return:
            Descriptor (str) of folder3 if exists, None otherwise
        """
        paths = path.split('/')

        files = files or self.get_files()
        parent_desc = self.root_id
        found = False
        for foldername in paths:
            if foldername != '':
                for file in files.items():
                    if (not (type(file[1]['a']) is dict)):
                        continue
                    if (file[1]['a'] and file[1]['t']
                            and file[1]['a']['n'] == foldername):
                        if parent_desc == file[1]['p']:
                            parent_desc = file[0]
                            found = True
                if found:
                    found = False
                else:
                    return None
        return parent_desc
```